# Why do we use »unterbringen« with Dativ instead of Akkusativ?

Tags: grammatical-case

> Erstellen Sie eine ungeordnete Liste mit allen Punkten, die Sie in **dem** Text unterbringen möchten.

I can not understand why we have Dativ here, instead od Akkusativ. It is a motion, something is happening. Still it is written in Dativ.

Comment: Being a movement-verb is not the whole story. You can *laufen ins Haus* but also *laufen im Haus*. In both cases you move.

Comment: Could you explain the difference to me? I always though that Dativ has to do something with the place, and Akkusativ with the motion.

Comment: Exactly. If you were talking about moving points into the text, accusative it is, but you are talking about points in the text, i.e. where (not where to), hence dative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Akkusativ

You use accusative case if the object is some kind of direction. You can ask for if with the word »wohin« (where to).

> Ich gehe in **die** Stadt. Ich gehe *wohin*?
>   I walk into the city. I walk *where to*?
>
> Ich fahre in **den** Wald. Ich fahre *wohin*?
>   I drive into the wood. I drive *where to*?
>
> Ich laufe in **das** Haus. Ich laufe *wohin*?
>   I run into the house. I run *where to*?

---

### Dativ

You use dative case if the object is some kind of place. You can ask for if with the word »wo« (where).

> Ich gehe in **der** Stadt. Ich gehe *wo*?
>   I walk in the city. I walk *where*?
>
> Ich fahre in **dem** Wald. (in + dem = im, so better: Ich fahre **im** Wald.) Ich fahre *wo*?
>   I drive in the wood. I drive *where*?
>
> Ich laufe in **dem** Haus. (better: Ich laufe **im** Haus.) Ich laufe *wo*?
>   I run in the house. I run *where*?

---

The point in your example is, that the verb »unterbringen« (to place; to store) is something that you do not *to* a place, but *at* a place. It is not a movement towards a target. It is an action that you perform *at* (not *to*) a given place. And this is the reason, why »unterbringe« needs dative case.

I know, you could say, that you move something to the place where you want to place/store it, but at least in this case you just have to accept, that the German word »unterbringen« doesn't work in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and thats correct. In this example "dem" is used, because you reference with what you want to interact (in this case the "Text").